# given new input in textbox is not updating in progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<script>
    function move() {
        var dolar= document.getElementById("no1").value;   
        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
        // var width = parseInt(dolar);
        var width = 500;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 5000);
        function frame() {
           width=parseInt(width)+parseInt(dolar);   
           if(width>=5000) {
               clearInterval(id);
           }
        elem.style.width = width + 'px'; 
        elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + 'px';
      }
   }
</script>
```

//the first input will increment in progress bar but the updated value would not get update in progress bar//

Comment: can you provide snippet??

Answer (score 1):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxw58jdo/)

I think its solve your problem...

```
function move() {
  var dolar= document.getElementById("no1").value;   
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 500;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5000);
  function frame() {
    width=parseInt(width)+parseInt(dolar);   
    if(width>=5000) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
    elem.style.width = width + 'px'; 
    elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + 'px';
  }
}
move();
```

Comment: progress bar is updating by that same number recursively until reach 5000...i want the output to be, first input is 200$ so (width+200) which is(500+200)=700 and at next time if we give input like 300 so the progressbar will increment by 700(previous value stored)+300(new input)

Answer (score 0):

Issues I found in this code snippet are as follows:

1. Updated value in input is not being added in "width".
2. "NaNpx" is displayed as value of "myBar" when input "no1" is **empty**.

To address above issues,

1. Pull definition of "dolar" inside "frame" function.
2. Just add undefined/null check before adding "dolar" in "width"

Below code should work fine:

```
<script>
    function move() {
        var dolar;
        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
        var width = 500;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 5000);
        function frame() {
           dolar = document.getElementById("no1").value;
           width = width + (!dolar ? 0 : dolar * 1);
           if (width >= 5000) {
               clearInterval(id);
           }
           elem.style.width = width + 'px'; 
           elem.innerHTML = width + 'px';
        }
    }
    move()
</script>
```